Joining 2 tables but only show values from 2nd table once in 1st table
I've been racking my brain trying to solve this problem. I'm using Presto SQL.
I have 2 tables:
trx (transactions per day):
| date       | usage    | deposit_id |
| -----------| -------- |------------|
| 2024-08-12 | 2,500    | DEP001     |
| 2024-08-14 | 3,500    | DEP002     |
| 2024-08-15 | 3,500    | DEP002     |

deposit (customers doing deposit):
| deposit_date | deposit_id | deposit_amount|
| -------------| -----------|---------------|
| 2024-08-12   | DEP001     | 1,000,000     |
| 2024-08-13   | DEP002     |  500,000      |

I want the joined tables to be (transactions coming from each deposit):
| date       | usage    | deposit_id | deposit_amount
| -----------| -------- |------------|---------------
| 2024-08-12 | 2,500    | DEP001     |   1,000,000
| 2024-08-13 |   0      | DEP002     |    500,000
| 2024-08-14 | 3,500    | DEP002     |      0
| 2024-08-15 | 3,500    | DEP002     |      0

Basically I want the 2 tables to be joined and show usage when on the date where is usage, and deposit_amount on the date where there is a deposit. And I also want to keep on tracking the deposit_id for each usage.
Left/Right/Inner Join wont work as there would be dates not showing.
Please help! Thank you
I've tried left, right, inner join but it won't work. Also explored union all and group by but it would show blanks in the final table.

Can you only have one record per date/deposit_id in each of the tables?

@NickW No since there would be more transactions and deposits coming

"I've tried left, right, inner join ..."  So where's this query you have tried???  We don't see it.

I don't know Presto so you may need to adjust the syntax, but this might be one way of doing it:
WITH DATASET AS (
SELECT 
T.TRX_DATE, T.USAGE, T.DEPOSIT_ID T_DEPOSIT_ID
,D.DEPOSIT_DATE, D.DEPOSIT_ID D_DEPOSIT_ID, D.DEPOSIT_AMOUNT
FROM TRX T
FULL JOIN DEPOSIT D ON T.TRX_DATE = D.DEPOSIT_DATE AND T.DEPOSIT_ID = D.DEPOSIT_ID
)
SELECT
COALESCE(TRX_DATE, DEPOSIT_DATE) DATE
,NVL(USAGE,0) USAGE
,COALESCE(T_DEPOSIT_ID, D_DEPOSIT_ID) DEPOSIT_ID
,NVL(DEPOSIT_AMOUNT, 0) DEPOSIT_AMOUNT
FROM DATASET
ORDER BY COALESCE(TRX_DATE, DEPOSIT_DATE) ASC
;

